# Cant Fix DtypeWarning

Tags: python, pandas, csv, types, dask

I have a dataframe I am importing from a csv where I specify all dtypes on import. Here is how I am importing:

```
dd.read_csv(file, header=0, parse_dates = ['date'], dtype={'area_rural_sq_km': 'float64',
       'area_sq_km': 'float64',
       'area_urban_sq_km': 'float64',
        'country_name' : 'object',     
...   
       'cumulative_recovered': 'float64',
       'cumulative_recovered_age_0': 'float64'})
```

Although, I continue to get
`DtypeWarning: Columns (2,3,700) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.`
Whenever I try to do any computations, for example

```
dask_df.new_deceased.mean().compute()
```

I get the above error. There's some strange things though. Both column 2 and 3 are object types, and should not be involved in the computation. In addition they are specified on import as object types.

```
Dask Series Structure:
npartitions=504
    object
       ...
     ...  
       ...
       ...
Name: country_name, dtype: object
Dask Name: getitem, 10737 tasks
```

Another oddity is that I do not have a column 700, I only have 262 columns total.

I've thought about changing the types from object to string, although, when I try to export using to_hdf() it gives an error that strings are not supported, thus I would like to keep them as an object dtype.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the number of columns does not match your expectations points to a possible malformatting of the csv (e.g. unescaped commas).

Comment: But if that was the case I would be able to view column number 700 with dask_df.iloc[:,700]? But this gives me an error that it does not exist.

Comment: Not necessarily, dask uses a small snippet of the raw data to determine the structure. So if there is a mismatch between early part of the file and the rest of the file, dask wouldn't know immediately, only when computing.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion then? my dataset is over 20 GB so I cant inspect it by hand, and I don't know how to inspect a column that doesnt exist in my dataframe.

Comment: Hmm, it's tough to give general advice... perhaps you can share a few rows to at least get a sense of which columns could be problematic (e.g. a column with addresses or names might have unescaped quotes).